# Why isn't the Transition Altitude depicted on SID charts?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, altitude, sid-star

Why isn't the Transition Altitude depicted on SID charts?

I would assume it would be a relevant information to be presented on this type of chart.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**FAA**

Because it is a fixed value at 18,000 feet.

**ICAO-style and Jeppesen**

They show the TA (and sometimes the TL) on SID charts.

---

ICAO Annex 4 confirms the depiction on SID charts (chapter 9):

> 9.9.4.1 The components of the established relevant air
>   traffic services system shall be shown.
>
> (...)
>
> 5) transition altitude/height to the nearest higher 300 m or
>   1 000 ft;

Answer (score 1):

It is shown, when necessary.

But some SID procedures may not go high enough to be worried about TA. eg if a US SID only went out to say 10,000ft, then they wouldn't need TA on the plate.

Europeans tend to have a lower TA than the US, so the tendency is for the SID to climb through TA, and so it needs to be on the plate.